# AWS S3 CLI move files with a new name

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line, aws-cli

I have millions of images that need to be renamed. All files have a 'C' in part of the filename that needs to be changed to a lower 'c'.

File name pattern:

- ACD_112_2P-001-1**C**.jpg should be changed to ACD_112_2P-001-1**c**.jpg
- ACD_112_2P-002-2**C**.jpg should be changed to ACD_112_2P-002-2**c**.jpg
- ACD_112_2P-003-3**C**.jpg should be changed to ACD_112_2P-003-3**c**.jpg

How can I use AWS CLI with some kinda wild card to achieve this?

Source and destination buckets will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Using aws cli and bash you can rename multiple files like so:

```
$ for f in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket sample-bucket-1 --prefix "" --delimiter "" | grep replaceme | cut  -d ":" -f 2 | tr -d , | tr -d \";
do aws s3 mv s3://sample-bucket-1/$f s3://sample-bucket-1/${f/replaceme/replaced};
done
```

Where 'replaceme' is the part of the filename you wish to replace and 'replaced' is what you want to insert in the filename.

The following will extract the filename from the response:

```
 cut  -d ":" -f 2 | tr -d , | tr -d \"
```

If the files are within folders in a bucket place the folder name in prefix:

```
--prefix "folder_name/sub_folder_name"
```

Edited from here: 
http://gerardvivancos.com/2016/04/12/Single-and-Bulk-Renaming-of-Objects-in-Amazon-S3/

Answer (score 2):

No, the AWS CLI cannot rename multiple files in one call.

Each rename operation will require a separate API call. It would probably be easier to do it with a program, such as a Python script. The script could **retrieve a list of objects** (or be given it), then make an Amazon S3 `copy()` call to **copy** the object to a new name, then **delete** the old object.

Answer (score 2):

great it works!
you are missing a final **)** for the loop for

$ for f in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket sample-bucket-1 --prefix "" --delimiter "" | grep replaceme | cut  -d ":" -f 2 | tr -d , | tr -d \"**)**;
do aws s3 mv s3://sample-bucket-1/$f s3://sample-bucket-1/${f/replaceme/replaced};
done

> $ for f in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket sample-bucket-1 --prefix "" --delimiter "" | grep replaceme | cut  -d ":" -f 2 | tr -d , | tr -d \";
>   do aws s3 mv s3://sample-bucket-1/$f s3://sample-bucket-1/${f/replaceme/replaced};
>   done

Answer (score 0):

Use the aws CLI with [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq) to parse the json output. Don't try to parse json with `cut` and `tr` as some of the other answers do.

Also, perform more strict matches. In the below example, we use the regular expression `C\.jpg$` to match s3 items that only have a key ending in `C.jpg`.

And then be certain only to replace the trailing `C.jpg` by using the [`%` substring replacement](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PCTPATREF), which only replaces the trailing end of the string. Using `${var/C/c}` as the other answers seem to suggest would change the first match of `C` in the entire string, which may not be what you desire. For example, with the provided filenames given in the question, `ACD_112_2P-003-3C.jpg` would become `AcD_112_2P-003-3C.jpg` using `${var/C/c}`. Instead, use `${var/%C.jpg/c.jpg}` which is sure to replace `C.jpg` at the *end* of the string with `c.jpg`.

```
s3_bucket=your-bucket-name
# select all items from the json that have a key that ends in C.jpg.
jq_cmd='.Contents[].Key | select(test("C\.jpg$"))'

for orig in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket "$s3_bucket" | jq -r "$jq_cmd"); do
  # Replace the trailing C.jpg with c.jpg.
  new=${orig/%C.jpg/c.jpg}
  aws s3 mv "s3://$s3_bucket/$orig" "s3://$s3_bucket/$new"
done
```